# How do I turn a dict and an array into a list?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a dictionary "a" and an array "b"

"a" looks somewhat like this:

```
{Volvo: 657898, Volkswagen: 387564}... etc
```

and "b" looks like this:

```
[['Volvo' 'VO']
['Volkswagen' 'VW']]
... etc
```

How do I compare them, and make a list that looks like this:

```
[['Volvo', 'VO', 657898],
['Volkswagen', 'VW', 387564],
etc...
```

Comment: What have you tried? Show us your code.

Comment: How? With a script. Or by hand if your prefer.

Comment: I haven't tried anything yet, since I have no clue what to do, tbh.
I am still very new to Python, and I am working on a rushed exam-project atm, so I I've tried to search for an answer, but found none online

Comment: Surely you should have an idea on how to do this logically, that is significantly more important regardless of how much Python you know. For example, iterating through the array and using the value of the first index in each sub array to get the HashMap numbers, then appending that number to what sub array your currently on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a `for-loop`.

**Demo:**

```
import numpy as np
d = {"Volvo": 657898, "Volkswagen": 387564}
l = np.array([['Volvo', 'VO'],['Volkswagen', 'VW']]).tolist()

for i in l:
    i.append(d.get(i[0]))
print(l)   #If you want to convert it back to numpy array use l = np.asarray(l)
```

**Output:**

```
[['Volvo', 'VO', 657898], ['Volkswagen', 'VW', 387564]]
```

Comment: i.append(d[i[0]])

It gives me an error, saying that nparray's don't have any append-method.
Do I have to turn the array into a list first, somehow?

Comment: Updated snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much! I really appreciate your help a lot :)

Comment: You are welcome :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a *list comprehension*.

```
result = [item + [a[item[0]]] for item in b]
```

Output

```
[['Volvo', 'VO', 657898], ['Volkswagen', 'VW', 387564]]
```